# Linking polyline features on web map to Google Chart?

Tags: leaflet, chart

I would like to display a line chart and (leaflet) map beside each other on a web page. When I turn off a series on the chart the associated polyline feature (river) should turn off on the map. I am having trouble finding examples of this functionality. Is it possible?

Comment: Polygons (geojson) can should be straightforward to implement line charts - would suggest the charts are contained in the html pop-up - see the 'Senior Citizens' example and click on a polygon http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/demos/arcgis-server/

Comment: @Mapperz that link is broken - is it retrievable and can your comment perhaps be made into an answer?