# Linking Leaflet Js GeoJson Data to a Chart

Tags: leaflet, line, chart

I am looking for a way to link the drawn polyline to a chart with leaflet js. I want the position in the chart to be highlighted, when I hover over the polyline and vice versa. Basically what runtastic does on their website (I linked an image in the bottom). Right now I am using HighCharts and am quite satisfied with it. I discovered [Linking polyline features on web map to Google Chart?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68933)

However it wasn't really answered and the link in the comment leads to a 404 page.

[image]